# SQL query to append a column which counts the # instance of a particular ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I run analytics for a call center that more or less cold calls leads our customers give us from their CRM to sell/upsell software. I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate pick up rates based on the 1st call, 2nd call, 3rd call, etc. All data associated with our call center is logged in a table in PostgreSQL, each contact has a unique ID and each call has a unique ctc_id. My thought is to order the table by created_at/ctc_id ASC, then append a calculated column to count the number-th occurrence of the contact ID for each contact_id in a dial session/campaign [let's call it **nTH_Call**]. With that, I could group by **nTH_Call**, and based on a pickup vs voicemail (or any other negative call disposition), calculate a pickup rate based on N-th attempt to call each contact. An example table below hopefully illustrates my question:

| ctc_id | call_time | contact_id | nTH_Call |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 347723 | 2021-04-06 14:14:13.287698 | 163836 | 1 |
| 354172 | 2021-04-12 09:29:02.564833 | 81153 | 1 |
| 354174 | 2021-04-12 09:29:09.759067 | 81153 | 2 |
| 367971 | 2021-04-21 11:57:26.050931 | 81153 | 3 |
| 369961 | 2021-04-22 11:45:40.009285 | 163836 | 2 |
| 374106 | 2021-04-26 13:41:10.687522 | 163836 | 3 |

In a way, I'm also trying to answer - "It takes about X.X dials (on average) to get a customer to pickup on a cold call..." etc. as well as "by the 2nd call, our average pick up rates are X.X% and by the 3rd call through, our average pick up rates are X.X%..." etc.

If it were in Excel and I had the data in a table, I'd do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns3SC.png) --
With a `=COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)` in cell D2, and drag the formula down, then pivot the data however I'd want. But I'm trying to illustrate the rates real time on a live dashboard programmatically.

Any ideas or radically different methods I can try to answer my questions? What would I need to do in my SQL statement to make this happen?

Any help would be appreciated.

Sample Query:

```
SELECT
  ctc_id,
  call_time,
  contact_id,
  [contact_id OCCURRENCE order count column here!!]
FROM
  call_table
ORDER BY 
  call_time ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the nth_call order by contact in this way:

```
SELECT
  ctc_id,
  call_time,
  contact_id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by contact_id order by call_time) as nth_call
FROM
  call_table
ORDER BY 
  call_time ASC
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you Jayvee!